# Python CSV Write Object

Tags: python, csv

I have a class called TwitterObject that stores two variables (post, sentiment). I want to output this data to CSV in the following format:

```
post,sentiment
'This is a twitter post', 'pos'
'This is another twitter post', 'neg'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
def OutputCSV(csv_file):
    csv_columns = ['post','sentiment']
    with open(csv_file, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
        writer.writeheader()
        for TwitterObject.TwitterObject in ApplicationModel.ApplicationModel.getTwitterObjects():
            writer.writerow(str(TwitterObject.TwitterObject.post))
```

Twitter Object

```
class TwitterObject(object):

    def __init__(self, post, sentiment):

        self.post = post
        self.sentiment = sentiment
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'R', 'T', ' ', '@', 'O', 'l', 'i', 'P', 'r', 'i', 'c', 'e', 'B', 'a', 't', 'e', 's', ':', ' ', 'G', 'r', 'a', 'n',
```

Comment: So you want them all on one line? or each post on a separate line?

Comment: Are you getting any error? What is the question?

Comment: I would like it with a post and sentiment value on the same line. A new line is required for each new TwitterObject(post,sentiment)

Comment: This is the error: ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'R', 'T', ' ', '@', 'O', 'l', 'i', 'P', 'r', 'i', 'c', 'e', 'B', 'a', 't', 'e', 's', ':', ' ', 'G', 'r', 'a', 'n',

Comment: I've posted the solution that I was looking for. Once again, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Thank you too heinst & Francesco for pointing me in the write direction. Using your code, I got it working like this:

```
@staticmethod
    def OutputCSV(csv_file):
        csv_columns = ['post','sentiment']
        with open(csv_file, 'w') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
            writer.writerow(csv_columns)
            for TwitterObject.TwitterObject in ApplicationModel.ApplicationModel.getTwitterObjects():
                writer.writerow({
                    TwitterObject.TwitterObject.post,
                    TwitterObject.TwitterObject.sentiment
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

The [writer.writerow](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) expects a sequence and you are giving it a string, which is why each letter is a separate field. Try something like:

```
writer.writerow({'post': str(TwitterObject.TwitterObject.post), 'sent': str(TwitterObject.TwitterObject. sentiment)})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have chosen to use a [DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) so the `writerow` method accepts a `dict` as a parameter.

You should change the `writerow` line with something like

```
writer.writerow({
    'post': TwitterObject.TwitterObject.post,
    'sentiment': TwitterObject.TwitterObject.sentiment
    })
```

Answer (score -2):

python has a csv writer library:

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                        quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```